# Javascript window.load events not triggering without using setTimeout

Tags: javascript, shopify

This question pertains to a shopify cart page.
I am trying to manipulate a page on load with Javascript. 'DOMContentLoaded' was not reliable enough so I am using the window.load event. The problem I am facing is, if I do not use the setTimeout function in the 'load' event, I am unable to hide the div "checkout-parameters", or even attach an eventlistener to the select tag "pickup-items". However, when I add a 2 second delay, every thing works as expected. That is, the div gets hidden as required and event listener gets attached to the select tag.

I am trying to understand if I am missing out any thing, and why I need to set a delay. Shouldn't the window.load automatically take care of everything?

The console.log lines print perfectly normally in all cases.

For extra information, the document.readyState returns 'complete'.

This is the pickup.js file.

```
const pickupItemsFunction= () => {
    console.log("Hi");
    let el = document.getElementById('checkout-parameters')
    console.log(el.style.display);
    el.style.display = "none";
    console.log(el.style.display);
    let selectTag = document.getElementById("pickup-items");
    selectTag.addEventListener('change', logSelectedStore);

}

const logSelectedStore = (el) => {
    let selectTag = document.getElementById("pickup-items");
    console.log(selectTag.value);


}

window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
    console.log(document.readyState);
    setTimeout(pickupItemsFunction, 2000);
});
```

Comment: Try to use normal function pickupItemsFunction() { ... }

Comment: arrow functions have limitants.

Comment: More detail is needed.  It appears that you are trying to embed javascript in a Shopify page, which may have dynamic content. Shopify has its own events to notify that sections have been loaded or modified.  You'll probably need to add event handlers for those. Using a timer for this is not a good solution.

Comment: @JorgeMejia I switched to regular function pickupItems() {} and removed the timer. Unfortunately it does not attach the event listener.

Comment: Instead window.addEventListener try to use selfe executing function, (function() {
   // your page initialization code here
   // the DOM will be available here

})();

Comment: @JorgeMejia surprisingly, it is able to see the element selectTag in the pickupFunction when I log it to the console. But the eventlistener is still not getting attached.

Comment: @Yogi I believe the eventlisteners are dependent on the theme. I will check them out, and report back if I have any success.